# Python voice assistant "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gtts

I'm trying to make a voice assistant with python in VSCode but have trouble. I installed all modules already, but one of the modules is not working. The `gTTs`(Google Text-to-Speech) make a error which is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
```

I installed `gTTs` with pip installer in the terminal, again and again, but it did not happen anything. It just shows me:

```
"Requirement already satisfied"
```

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import time
import playsound

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
    filename = 'jarvis_email_alert.mp3'
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

    speak("hello time")
```

[image: gTTS error]

[image: in code line]

```
PS C:\Users\huzey\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python> &  C:/Users/huzey/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.8.exe 
c:/Users/huzey/OneDrive/Masaüstü/Python/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:/Users/huzey/OneDrive/Masaüstü/Python/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
PS C:\Users\huzey\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python>
```

How can I get the solution?

Comment: What exact command did you use to install the module?

Comment: I try many ways for fix this problem. Here are some ways I tried. 1) `pip install gTTS` 2) `pip uninstall gTTS` and `pip install gTTS` again. 3) Completely uninstall VS code and I installed gTTs again.

Comment: It sounds like you have two different versions of Python on your system.  Show us the output of these commands: `python --version` (or whatever command you use to run python) and `pip --version`

Comment: While  a python file is opened  in VSCode,  if you click on 'Python"  at the bottom right of the editor window,  it shows you `Python Related Settings`. If you click on it, you can see/alter which python environment VSCode is using.  There are easier ways of [checking this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), but they've never worked for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that your pip is using a different python version than your script

you can use `python -m pip install gtts` to install `gtts` to your python environment

Comment: when I use `C:\Users\huzey>python -m pip install gtts` it only shows Requirement already satisfied answers.   Like this;                                                                                                       Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\huzey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->gtts) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\huzey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->gtts) (2021.10.8)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't, try to restart Vscode after a pip install

Comment: Your solution didn't work sorry

Comment: This should most likely be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem. İt seemed my system have two different python version. After realizing that I remove all pythons in system and install only one version of python. Before doing this when I open CMD and checking python version I seemed python 3.10 but the same time when I open VS code and checking python version it was showing me  version of python 3.8. Now system have version of python 3.8.10 and working clearly!
(after fixing a few line errors :))

Thank you for your ideas.